# The Nettle packages do not seem to install RSA functions on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, package-management, compiling

From the package manager, I installed the Nettle libraries *libnettle7*, *libhogweed5*, *nettle-bin*, and *nettle-dev*, which appear to be based on Nettle 3.5.1. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. After this, I was able to write two programs using AES and SHA algorithms, which worked fine, so I know that the header pathing is correct.

However, I could not call RSA functions without getting compiler errors.

```
$ make rsa_test
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccaqGeCe.o: in function `main':
rsa_test.cc:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `nettle_rsa_public_key_init'
/usr/bin/ld: rsa_test.cc:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `nettle_rsa_private_key_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:9: rsa_test] Error 1
```

Here is minimal code that produces the error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <nettle/rsa.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct rsa_public_key pub;
  struct rsa_private_key priv;
  rsa_public_key_init(&pub);
  rsa_private_key_init(&priv);
}
```

The file rsa.h is present in /usr/include/nettle, and contains the functions rsa_public_key_init and rsa_public_key_init. How can I install the RSA functions and call them?

Comment: Does your Makefile actually link the library/libraries? Header files don't usually "contain" functions - just *declarations*.

Comment: The Nettle manual states that the link flag is "-lnettle", which is present in my Makefile. 
EDIT: It looks like there are supposed to be 1-2 additional links, depending on which functions are called. This may explain the undefined references.

Comment: Yeah I had a poke around using `nm -D` and it looks like the nettle_rsa_XXX functions are in the hogweed library - so try `-lnettle -lhogweed`